# Assign values based on priority in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a **Designation** table which has values like:

```
Designation       Priority
--------------------------
President         1
Founder           1
managing director 2
creative director 3
ceo               3
ict director      4
dpo               5
school director   6
```

and an **Employee** table:

```
Name  Designation
-----------------
john  president / school director
ralph ict director / dpo
ron   Managing Director / Founder
rex   Ceo/Creative Director
rick  ceo/president
nick  Founder / Managing Director
```

The output I am expecting is this:

```
john   president 
ralph  ict director
ron    founder
rick   president
nick   founder
```

where the only the designation having the higher rank over the one adjacent to it should be in the result set.

Is this type of problem even possible in SQL or do I have to use Python? I'm using SQL Server 2019. The values of the Designation column in the Employee table has designations delimited by "/".

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: Do you really have delimited values like `'president / school director'` in your database, or those actually stored in two different rows?

Comment: It appears to me that you need a designation table ..  And then use a `JOIN STATEMENT` to join all three tables .. Then `ORDER BY ASC` designation ..

Comment: @gmb ,yes they are delimited by "/". some are added together ,some are in another rows.

Comment: @Zak, Designation table is already there having designation and it's priority.There are only 2 tables - designation and employee.Yes i need to join but how to put the logic based on priority, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about your *relational* database wrong.   You are going to need  realistically 3 tables.

```
employee
+-------------------+------------+
|    employee_id    |    name    |
+-------------------+------------+
|         1         |    John    |
|         2         |    Jane    |
+-------------------+------------+

designation
+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|    designation_id    |    designation_name     |    priority    |
+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|          1           |    president            |       1        |
|          2           |    school director      |       1        |
|          3           |    ict director         |       2        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+----------------+

designation_to_employee
+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
|   id    |   designation_id    |    employee_id    |
+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
|   1     |          1          |       1           |
|   2     |          2          |       1           |
|   3     |          3          |       2           |
+---------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

With those three tables there *is no need* for delimiting inside a table .. You can have multiple designations per employee --  AND you can then sort by said designations.

IE

```
SELECT a.name, c.designation_name from employee a

LEFT JOIN designation_to_employee b
ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id

LEFT JOIN designation c
ON b.designation_id = c.designation_id

ORDER BY c.priority ASC
```

Of course if you don't want John in the results twice, because he's a president AND a school director, you can `GROUP BY a.employee_id` or something like that ...  This should be enough to get you well on your way.  If you want *all* of John's designations, but in a single row, you are going to have to use a `NESTED SELECT` combined with `CONCAT` which is far beyond the scope of this OP, and needs to be a new question on SO if that's what you're attempting.  Get your DB set up correctly first, and attempt it.

Comment: ,thanks but it is not as easy as you have wrritten it!